# Проблема с позиционированием с помощью bottom (решено)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, позиционирование

Всем привет. есть у меня элемент с абсолютным позиционированием внутри контейнера в котором мефа подружается динамически. Что примечательно: если я его двигаю с помощью изменения показателя `top`, то он нормально перемещается(опускается) внутри контейнера, но если хочу сдвинуть с помощью `bottom` то ничего не выходит.. Изначально при задании `bottom=0` (top при этом не инициализирован) элемент сдвигается на пикселей 15 относительно начала и больше не двигается при задании ему значений. А т.к. контент формируется динамически - мне нужно позиционировать именно снизу контейнера. Что скажите?

```css
.product-frame {
  position: relative;
}
.view-grid-center .description-table {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  right: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  top:auto;
  width: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-grid-center">
<div class="product-frame">
  <table class="description-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="product-quantity">
          <div class="quantity buttons_added">
            <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="27" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
            <span>порц.</span>
            <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
            <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Вопрос решен - нужно было добавить `top:auto;`, тк.к был стиль приоритетом ниже, который определял положение блока, несмотря на мой `bottom`

Answer (score 1):

**Обновлённый ответ**

У вас внешние блоки (`.view-grid-center` и `.product-frame`) имеют нулевую высоту.

Соответственно, когда вы позиционируете таблицу, используя `bottom`, то низ таблицы «прилепляется» к низу внешнего блока (с `position: relative`). Таким образом, всё съезжает выше, чем при использовании `top`.

Comment: да, при копировании ошибся - забыл заменить table на div. вопрос остается по-прежнему открытым

Comment: @Вася Вы в примере представьте код, который у вас не работает (с `bottom`). И объясните что мы должны увидеть в сниппете, потому как я не могу понять что вы хотите спозиционировать.

Comment: @Вася У вас в примере ещё `.view-grid-center` в CSS есть, а в HTML его нету.

Comment: `.view-grid-center` теперь есть) сорри, упрощал с рабочего примера, поэтому вылезли косяки. `bottom` установил для `description-table`

Comment: даже тут видно, если выполнить код - он верх поднялся и сгруппировался, что не наблюдается, если `top` задавать

Comment: @Вася Обновил ответ. Или у вас пример слишком упрощённый, или вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: наконец-то разобрался! все делал так, но там была круче фишка - может, для себя возьмете на вооружение - мне по крайней мере это было не очевидно. как вы правильно заметили - пример был упрощенный, т.к. в стилях оказывается еще было определено порядком ниже для этого блока: `position:absolute; top:21px` так вот - этот `top` и определял положение блока, хотя у моего `bootom` приоритет выше! добавил `top:auto` и все заработало!

Comment: Нету такого понятия, как приоритет больше. Только одинаковые свойства друг друга перекрывают. А разные свойства начинают вместе работать. В вашем случае это привело к неожиданному эффекту. Если мой ответ помог с вашим вопросом, отметьте его, пожалуйста.

Comment: частично помог, что я и отметил плюсами, а к итоговому решению я пришел сам, к сожалению, в вашем ответе намека на переопределение `top` не содержалось, посему имеем то, что имеем - думаю, вы со мной согласитесь

Comment: Ок. В вашем коде `top` тоже не было :)